# Gmail Script: Edit filter

Tags: filter, google-apps-script, gmail

Is it possible to edit or create filters in Gmail with a Google apps script? Background: I have a filter, that deletes emails from specified addresses. It is annoying to add addresses manually to the filter. Therefore I want to select an email, press a button to add the sender to the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create or edit filters inside Gmail using Google Scripts. You can however create a Google Script function that triggers every minute or so on incoming email and it will work like a filter.

Here's a snippet. You can refer to [Advanced Gmail filters](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-filters/4875/) for more examples.

```
function gmailRule() {
  var blacklist = ["email1", "email2", "email3"];  
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread label:inbox");
  for (var t in threads) {
    var msg = threads[t].getMessages()[0];
    if (msg.getFrom().indexOf(blacklist) !== -1)
      threads[t].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there no better solution than checking every minute? Can you trigger a function when an email arrives?

Comment: Gmail cannot call Google Script, it is the other way around.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal The fact that you say "Gmail does not read google scripts" does not indicate that "google script does not create a filter"